# AppAuthenticator Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I want to put an authenticator in my API, this anthenticator have to check if the ID given in the headers is in my database. The problem is that I don't understand how this work.
I have read the docs but keep don't understand. (Maybe because of my english).
My API don't need login and password, I just want him to check at every request.
 For now I have an error :

```
 Uncaught PHP Exception UnexpectedValueException: "The App\Security\AppAuthenticator::getUser() method must return a UserInterface. You returned boolean
```

But i'm sure that I have a lot of another problem in my code.

There is my AppAuthenticator :

```
class AppAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'token' => $request->headers->has('DDMDL-AUTH-TOKEN'),
        ];
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $apiToken = $credentials['token'];

        if (null === $apiToken) {
            return;
        }

        require __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "Entity" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "sqlconnect.php";
        $auth = 'SELECT ID FROM MOBILEDDMDL WHERE ID = :idtel ';
        $prepauth = $pdo->prepare($auth);
        $prepauth->execute(array(':idtel' => $apiToken));
        $user = $prepauth->fetch();
        if ($user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Pas autorisé');
        }

        return $user;


        //return $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['apiToken' => $apiToken]);


    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        // todo
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        // todo
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        // todo
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        // todo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getUser() want you to return a UserInterface instead instead of your boolean. I believe your User::class extends UserInterface so the commented line was the correct variable to return:

```
//return $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['apiToken' => $apiToken]);
```

My getUser looks like :

```
public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
    if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
        throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
    }

    if(strpos($credentials['identifiant'], '@') !== false){
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Utilisateur::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['identifiant']]);
    } else {
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Utilisateur::class)->findOneBy(['identifiant' => $credentials['identifiant']]);
    }


    if (!$user) {
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Aucun utilisateur trouvé avec ce nom de compte');
    }
    return $user;
}
```

checkCredential is the method which verify the password or whatever and this method will return true of false (if the user connexion is ok or not)

My checkCredential looks like :

```
 public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
{
    $passOk1 = password_verify($credentials['password'], $user->getMdp());
    $passOk = md5($credentials['password']) === $user->getMdp();
    $credential = false;
    if($passOk || $passOk1) {
        $user->setDerniereConnexion(new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        $this->entityManager->clear();
        $credential = true;
    }
    return $credential;
}
```

Comment: ok but the user is the one created by symfony with the cmd, I don't know how to use it, do you have a link for this ?

Comment: The user created by Symfony is just a "normal" entity/class but which extends UserInterface which allow Symfony to use this class as "connexion user". You can edit this User::class like you want. Now you have to finish implementing your methods with TODO. I'm going to update my post to share you my LoginFormAuthenticator